# What's an alternative to echo grep in parsing a running log?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, grep, echo

I'm currently figuring my way around a bash script (sorry, can't use other languages like perl) to keep track of a running log during a server startup. Basically, I have to trigger certain events depending on whether or not i run into certain strings or patterns while the log is being written. Currently, i have this code:

```
LOG=path_to_logfile
LINE1="[1-9][0-9]* some string"
LINE2="another string"
LINE3="third string"

tail -fn0 $LOG | \
while read line
do
 echo $line | grep "$LINE1" || echo $line | grep "$LINE2" || echo $line | grep "$LINE3"

 if [ $? = 0 ]
 then
      TMP=<echo line above>

      ... bunch of conditional statements...
 fi
done
```

However, this is kinda slow; by the time the line i need to track is detected by the echo/grep combinations using or, it's waaaay after the server already started up. What's a good alternative to the above? I've read awk should be used but when i tried writing it in awk, either i wrote it wrong or the processing was also taking too much time to finish.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are you tailing? Which server log?

Comment: I'm starting up a jboss server, which let's just say has /path/to/server.log as the log file. Sorry, just edited the code as I typed this in my mobile so the formatting was whacked out.

Comment: Unfortunately, as soon as the output of tail -f goes trough a pipe, the stream is buffered and everything after the pipe no longer reflects the real time of log being written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than calling `grep` (potentially several times) on each line, let `bash` do the regular expression matching.

```
LOG=path_to_logfile
LINE1="[1-9][0-9]* some string"
LINE2="another string"
LINE3="third string"

tail -fn0 $LOG | while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $LINE1|$LINE2|$LINE3 ]]; then
        TMP=<echo line above>
         ... bunch of conditional statements...
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like this instead:

```
tail -fn0 $LOG | egrep "$LINE1|$LINE2|$LINE3" | \
    while read TMP
    do
        ...
    done
```

That way, the `while read` loop, which at a guess is going to be the slowest part of this whole operation, is only invoked when `egrep` actually finds a matching line in the input log.

Comment: Makes sense, will try this. My problem with the above was everytime I changed the echo/grep part, when I read the variable line, it wasn't updated (i.e. the process detected a match but the log line being read wasn't updated yet with the latest line). Hope that made sense. But I'll go try egrep. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple match statements, which are `OR`ed together to see if the line matches:

```
tail -f -n0 "$LOG" | grep -e "$LINE1" -e "$LINE2" -e "$LINE3" | while IFS= read -r line
do
    # Do something with each matching $line
done
```